# Does my app need to be retested if I only updated the Marketplace Details

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I update marketplace details for my WP7 app and it looks like it has gone back for certification, I did not update the .Xap. Is this normal, and if so, is it any quicker than standard certification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's purely visual. A details change won't require a re-validation. However, it might take several days for the marketplace to reflect your changes.

(Talking from experience here)

Comment: did it lock you out from updating your app though?

Comment: I didn't try to update the app. But I would assume you get locked out, since you can ALSO change the marketplace details in a regular XAP update.